# How to view metaspace area in heap dump?

Tags: java, heap-dump, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I got the `OutOfMemoryError : Metaspace` in my tomcat.
And I got heap dump file of jvm. (I use java8)

So I want to view only metaspace area in heap dump(hprof format), but I can't know how to do that.

I use MAT(Eclipse Memory Analyzer) to analyze the heap dump file.

Can I view only metaspace area?

Thanks.

Comment: Refer link:-
Basic Concepts of Java Heap Dump Analysis with MAT :- https://medium.com/@chrishantha/basic-concepts-of-java-heap-dump-analysis-with-mat-e3615fd79eb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't direct metaspace information in a HPROF file.
Your might have a class loader leak or duplicate classes.
Try reading [Permgen vs Metaspace in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-permgen-metaspace) or 
[The Unknown Generation: Perm](https://sites.google.com/site/eclipsebiz/The-Unknown-Generation-Perm)